# How do I keep a fixed header on top if there's a small strip on top of it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Thank you so much for taking a look at my question.

I'm trying to Keep a header on top of the page using CSS's fixed positioning. the problem is that I have a small content strip on top of the header and when I scroll down the header stays fixed but the gap where the strip is supposed to be remains:

[image]

Here's the code that's handling all of this:

```css
.header-container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Strip -->
<div class="tp-top-bar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 tp-top-add">
        <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Monday - Friday : 8:00am - 5:00pm</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul class="tp-top-links">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--HEADER-->
<div class="header-container">
  <div class="tp-header">
    <div>......</div>
  </div>

  <div class="tp-navbar">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>home...
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

How would I prevent this gap from happening when scrolled? Do I need some jQuery? Basically I want the header to collapse on top and always remain on top somehow.... Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach a scroll event handler to the document and watch to see if the document has been scrolled past the height of your thin strip.  If it has, *that's* when you set the position of your header to fixed.  In the fiddle below, I'm adding & removing a class to/from the header to accomplish this:

[Fiddle w/ solution](https://jsfiddle.net/tburki/vr47a9s1/2/)

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#smallstrip').height()) { 
    $('#fixedheader').addClass('fixed');
    $('#content').css('margin-top', $('#fixedheader').height());
  }
  else {
    $('#fixedheader').removeClass('fixed');
    $('#content').css('margin-top', 0);
  }
});
```

**EDIT**: Updated the solution to account for extra padding/margin needed by the content to not see a "jump" when the header becomes fixed.  Instead of using jQuery's .css function you could also apply a class at the parent level and use CSS to do something like:

```
#parent.fixed #fixedheader{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#parent.fixed #content {
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

But that is dependent on you knowing the height of your fixed header.  If that is the case, I would go the straight CSS route instead of messing with CSS in jQuery.

Comment: Thanks you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

If the header is fixed, I'd recommend setting its position (top/left/right/bottom).

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > $('div.tp-top-bar').outerHeight()){
        $('div.tp-top-bar').hide();
        $('div.header-container').css({ top: 0 });
    } else {
        $('div.tp-top-bar').show();
        $('div.header-container').css({ top: $('div.tp-top-bar').outerHeight() });
    }
});
```